# Select a particular result from completion suggestions

Tags: bash, auto-completion

Let's say I have 3 files in a particular directory: `abc.txt, aww.txt, ant.txt`

If I do: `cat a` (and press tab to see options) terminal will display the 3 file names: `abc.txt, aww.txt, ant.txt`

Is there any way to select the nth result rather than typing, by specifying the index number in the results the terminal displayed?

something like: `cat a2` to get the second file (`aww.txt`)?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. In Zsh you can iterate over all the possible completions hitting TAB multiple times (i.e. e.g. hitting TAB 4 times will complete `ant.txt`). It can also be set up so that is possible to iterate backwards for a better navigation. That obviously implies changing the shell to Zsh though. If you consider that a good enough alternative I can write an answer for that.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you are using bash, either add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
bind '"\e[6~": menu-complete'
bind '"\e[5~": menu-complete-backward'
```

Or to change the defaults for all programs that use the readline completion library, not just bash, create the file `~/.inputrc` containing:

```
$include /etc/inputrc
"\e[6~": menu-complete
"\e[5~": menu-complete-backward
```

Now when you open a new terminal, you can press:

- <kbd>TAB</kbd> as normal to see available completions.
- <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd> to select the first completion or change to the next one.
- <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> to select the last completion or change to the previous one.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+n <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd> to select the nth completion or move forward n completions.

So for your example type <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd><kbd>Pg Dn</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Pg Dn</kbd> to get the second file `aww.txt`.

Comment: Let's pretend you are using `cd` and cycling over directories. What key do you press to "pick" that directory and start cycling the contents of that directory? Is there another thing to set/bind?

Comment: An alternative, if you don't want to move your hands too far from keyboard's home row, is to use Ctrl+Alt+P instead of PageUp and Ctrl+Alt+N instead of PageDown, which can be done via `bind '"\e\20": menu-complete-backward'` and `bind '"\e\16": menu-complete'`.