# Open a sub-directory using something rather than its name

Tags: command-line

I wonder if it's possible to open a sub-directory using something rather than its names, because some names are long and also sometimes they have meaningless parts(acronyms or etc.). Is there something like an index number(after entering ls) and a special command I can use for this purpose? Or do you have another solutions? Thanks.

Comment: If you just want to select the *n*th result from tab completion, then https://askubuntu.com/q/707202/158442 would be better. If you want a general solution for faster cd'ing, then autojump is better.

Comment: Thanks this is interesting. But unfortunately I can't change directory to my ~/.bashrc ($ cd ~/.bashrc). I checked my working directory and listed all sub-directories and files to make sure about it, and also tried both absolute and relative paths. I think it's not a problem worth posting a new question so can you help me?

Comment: `~/.bashrc` is a file, not a directory. You might want to edit it with `gedit` or `nano`.