# Bash: populate a file name from present directory

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash

Edit: Using bash.

I am in a directory that has several files in it.  As a quicker method than typing it out, I would like to get one of those file names to "type itself" on the command line.

So far, my command is

`mv`

I would now like to "select" a file name to "populate" onto the command line.

Comment: Hit `Tab` twice. and your shell ( to find out `echo $SHELL` or `getent passwd $USER | cut -d: -f7`) will show you your choices.

Comment: It now lists each file on a separate line below the line where I typed the command.  But, how do I get one to populate on the command line (besides highlight and copy).

Comment: You should type the first few characters of the filename, and hit `Tab` again. If what you typed uniquely specifies 1 file, that filename will be filled in, if not, you'll see another list.

Comment: I don't know of a shell that does that by default, you can do it with `dialog` (eg [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/239632/60747)). Or perhaps use something like `mc`, select file with cursors and then F6 to move/rename.

Comment: Fwiw, it's a pretty common [idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44471/display-a-menu-of-files-names-and-let-the-user-select-a-file-by-entering-a-numbe).

Comment: @waltinator that works.  Do you want to put that as an answer and I will mark as accepted?

Comment: Related: [Select a particular result from completion suggestions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707202/select-a-particular-result-from-completion-suggestions)

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice. and your shell ( to find out `echo $SHELL` or `getent passwd $USER | cut -d: -f7`) will show you your choices.

Then, type the first few characters of the filename, and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again. If what you typed uniquely specifies 1 file, that filename will be filled in, if not, you'll see another list.

Comment: I am finding that you don't need to press tab twice as the first step.  Do you want to edit that part out?